# How to make none-database model two attributes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.1

I'm a newbie in Laravel. Please guide me.

Port is a Model and Coordinates is a none database Model. There are 2 floats (`lat and long`) in the Port Model. When a Port is loaded from the database, the 2 floats are cast to a Coordinates object.

My first question is, how do I make a non-database model with two attributes?

My second question is, how do I make a cast 2 floats in Port Model with Coordinates object?

Here is my Code Coordinates Model none-database Model with two attributes

```
class Coordinates extends Model
{

//Add attribute
protected $attributes = ['latitude', 'longitude'];
}
```

and here is Port Model With

```
class Port extends Contracts\AppModel
 {
    protected $coordinates = Coordinates::class;

    protected $fillable=[
        'un_latitude',
        'un_longitude',
    ];

    function __construct(array $attributes = array())
    {
         $this->coordinates = Coordinates::class;
         $this->coordinates->latitude = $attributes["un_latitude"];
         $this->coordinates->longitude = $attributes["un_longitude"];
    }

}
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question with dots and commas. It's hard to read your question.

Comment: I have Done now please explain it. @Ruub

Answer (score 0):

Every Eloquent model is supposed to be linked to one table in a database, as far as I understand. Rather just add `latitude` and `longitude` as columns in your [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#migration-structure) to create the `port` table.